# Having trouble with creating variables in SQL Server 2012 Homework Assignment?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Specifically I am trying to create the variables and then populate them.

My source code thus far...

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]

DECLARE @HighBonusAMT money, @LowBonusAMTnotzero money;
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 INT;
SET @HighBonusAMT = (SELECT MAX(Bonus) FROM Sales.SalesPerson);
SET @LowBonusAMTnotzero = (SELECT MIN(Bonus) FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus <> $0);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 4000);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000);
```

My Source Code Readme...

Creates variables and then populates them to store the:

- Highest bonus amount
- Lowest bonus amount that is not 0
- Number of salespeople that have bonuses of 0
- Number of salespeople who have bonuses > $4000
- Number of salespeople who have bonuses > $4000Number of salespeople who have bonuses > $4000

What am I doing wrong when i get the error message which says :

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign multiple values to the integer variables in the following cases :

```
SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = (SELECT BusinessEntityID, Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID, Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 4000);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID, Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000);
```

**You can assign only a single value (atomic) to these variables.**

The variables `@NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero`, `NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4`, `@NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4` are of integer type which means they can only be assigned a singlew integer value i.e.values such as 10 or 251 or 1001.

the following query outputs two results :

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0
```

- BusinessEntityID
- Bonus

The variable cannot hold both these values. If you need both the values,you can define two variables to hold the value of each column.

**EDIT : I do not know your exact requirement, so from business
perspective this may not be ideal. But to give you an idea to get rid
of your SQL Server error message you can try this :**

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
DECLARE @HighBonusAMT money, @LowBonusAMTnotzero money
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero INT
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 INT
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 INT

DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZeroID INT
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4ID INT
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4ID INT


SET @HighBonusAMT = (SELECT MAX(Bonus) FROM Sales.SalesPerson);
SET @LowBonusAMTnotzero = (SELECT MIN(Bonus) FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus <> $0);

SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = SELECT TOP 1 Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = SELECT TOP 1 Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 4000
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = SELECT TOP 1 Bonus FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000


SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZeroID = SELECT TOP 1 BusinessEntityID Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4ID = SELECT TOP 1 BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 4000
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4ID = SELECT TOP 1 BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: After fixing the error i am now getting this error...  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Is there any way to make it forget the error and just return the values?

Comment: @JacobHeckman See my edited answer. Basically, you'd define multiple variables to hold the value of each column i.e. if you want values of 2 columns define two variables, if you want values of 3 columns define 3 variables and so on and so forth.

Comment: @JacobHeckman could you edit your question with your current query and let us know which row is producing the error?

Comment: @JacobHeckman Check the code in the edit section. This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Still getting the error... Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @JacobHeckman That's because **you are still trying to assign more than 1 value to the variable**. *That's the reason why, in my query, in the edit section, I make use of **TOP 1***.

Comment: So at this point I'm just going to have to throw in the towel, i have been working on this assignment for 2 weeks with no progress and it's due in 5 hours. I want to say thank you to those who have tried to assist me but it's not worth staying awake for 12 hours over. Needless to say when this class is over i never want to take a programming class again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to store an integer to the last three SELECTs?

Add a `COUNT`:

```
SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0);
```

...and so on.

Comment: I wish i could answer your question as it could be helpful to know that but my teacher is incredibly vague about what she wants us to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not worng, you want the number of sales people in last 3 variables.

**You can do that like this:**

USE [AdventureWorks2012]

```
DECLARE @HighBonusAMT money, @LowBonusAMTnotzero money;
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 INT;
SET @HighBonusAMT = (   SELECT MAX(Bonus) 
                        FROM Sales.SalesPerson )
SET @LowBonusAMTnotzero = (  SELECT MIN(Bonus) 
                             FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
                             WHERE Bonus <> $0  )
SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                       FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
                                       WHERE Bonus = $0 
                                       GROUP BY BusinessEntityID  )
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                          FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
                                          WHERE Bonus > 4000 
                                          GROUP BY BusinessEntityID  )
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                                               FROM Sales.SalesPerson 
                                                               WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000 
                                                               GROUP BY BusinessEntityID  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use aggregate functions to populate multiple variables in one statement by using `CASE` clauses in your aggregates, for example:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]

DECLARE @HighBonusAMT money, @LowBonusAMTnotzero money;
DECLARE @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 INT, @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 INT;


SELECT
    @HighBonusAMT = MAX(Bonus)
    ,@LowBonusAMTnotzero = MIN(CASE WHEN Bonus > 0 THEN Bonus END)
    ,@NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus = 0 THEN Bonus END)
    ,@NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus > 4000 THEN Bonus END)
    ,@NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Bonus BETWEEN 0 AND 4000 THEN Bonus END)
FROM
    Sales.SalesPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

Following value assignment to variables is giving you error because when you are using a scalar variable, you can assign only one value to the variable. Sub-queries you are using are returning more than one value. If you are looking for the count matching your filter criteria, use appropriate function and group by if needed. If you are grouping by businessentityid and if you have more than one businessentityid, there are chances that you will get table result set (which means returns more than one row). If you want count for each businessentityId matching the filter used, you can declare the variable as a table variable instead of scalar variable. Hope this is helpful !!

SET @NumberofSalespeopleBonusZero = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus = $0);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthan4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 4000);
SET @NumberofSalespeopleGreaterthanzerolessthanorequalto4 = (SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM Sales.SalesPerson WHERE Bonus > 0 AND Bonus <= 4000);